# How change titles color of my navbar when the user scrolls ? Prestashop

Tags: javascript, css, prestashop

I would like to change my color titles from my navigation bar when the user scrolls a bit. I work in Prestashop and we can add custom CSS and custom javascript to it.

I started by analyzing the id of the text of the navigation bar in the theme of my prestashop:
[image]

Then I created this little javascript:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
    var title= document.getElementById('title-text');
    if ( window.pageYOffset > 100 ) {
        title.classList.add("white_menu");
    } 
}
```

and this css:

```css
.white_menu{
color: white;
}
```

But it doesn't work :/ Did I forget something ?

Thanks in advance
Malaury

[image]

Comment: Are you looking to update the text color or the background color?

Comment: You can't select the title with this `var title= document.getElementById('title-text');` because `title-text` is a class, not an ID. Also there are multiple `title-text` items. So you need to use `document.getElementsByClassName()` and iterate over them https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this style in your CSS

```
.white_menu span {
    color: white;
}
```

Replace your JS with this one

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    var title = document.getElementById('header_menu');
    if (window.pageYOffset > 100) {
        title.classList.add("white_menu");
    } else {
        title.classList.remove("white_menu");
    }
}
```